# No color data passed to vertex shader

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glfw, glew

I was following [an OpenGL tutorial](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org) and got to a point where I should pass color data to the vertex shader, but all I get is a black cube. I know that the fragment shader gets colors from the vertex shader because i tested it with setting the color vec3 to 1,0,0 and it worked.

**Graphics Driver**: Nvidia 388.13

**OpenGL Version**: 4.3

**Drawing Cube:**

```
GLuint VertexArrayID;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
static const GLfloat g_vertex_buffer_data[] = {
    -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f, // triangle 1 : begin
    -1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // triangle 1 : end
    1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f, // triangle 2 : begin
    -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f, // triangle 2 : end
    1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
    1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
    1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
    -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
    -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
    1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
    1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f
};
GLuint vertexbuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_vertex_buffer_data), g_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 12*3);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
static const GLfloat g_color_buffer_data[] = {
    0.583f,  0.771f,  0.014f,
    0.609f,  0.115f,  0.436f,
    0.327f,  0.483f,  0.844f,
    0.822f,  0.569f,  0.201f,
    0.435f,  0.602f,  0.223f,
    0.310f,  0.747f,  0.185f,
    0.597f,  0.770f,  0.761f,
    0.559f,  0.436f,  0.730f,
    0.359f,  0.583f,  0.152f,
    0.483f,  0.596f,  0.789f,
    0.559f,  0.861f,  0.639f,
    0.195f,  0.548f,  0.859f,
    0.014f,  0.184f,  0.576f,
    0.771f,  0.328f,  0.970f,
    0.406f,  0.615f,  0.116f,
    0.676f,  0.977f,  0.133f,
    0.971f,  0.572f,  0.833f,
    0.140f,  0.616f,  0.489f,
    0.997f,  0.513f,  0.064f,
    0.945f,  0.719f,  0.592f,
    0.543f,  0.021f,  0.978f,
    0.279f,  0.317f,  0.505f,
    0.167f,  0.620f,  0.077f,
    0.347f,  0.857f,  0.137f,
    0.055f,  0.953f,  0.042f,
    0.714f,  0.505f,  0.345f,
    0.783f,  0.290f,  0.734f,
    0.722f,  0.645f,  0.174f,
    0.302f,  0.455f,  0.848f,
    0.225f,  0.587f,  0.040f,
    0.517f,  0.713f,  0.338f,
    0.053f,  0.959f,  0.120f,
    0.393f,  0.621f,  0.362f,
    0.673f,  0.211f,  0.457f,
    0.820f,  0.883f,  0.371f,
    0.982f,  0.099f,  0.879f
};
GLuint colorbuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &colorbuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorbuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_color_buffer_data), g_color_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
mat4 Projection = perspective(radians(45.0f), (float)4 / (float)3, 0.1f, 100.0f);
mat4 View = lookAt(
    vec3(x_Pos, y_Pos, z_Pos), 
    vec3(0, 0, 0), // looks at the origin
    vec3(0, 1, 0)  // Head is up (set to 0,-1,0 to look upside-down)
);
mat4 Model = mat4((float)scale);
mat4 mvp = Projection * View * Model;
GLuint MatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "MVP");
glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &mvp[0][0]);
```

**Main Loop:**

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_D) == GLFW_PRESS) z_Pos -= 1;
if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_A) == GLFW_PRESS) z_Pos += 1;
if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_W) == GLFW_PRESS) y_Pos += 1;
if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_S) == GLFW_PRESS) y_Pos -= 1;
if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_UP) == GLFW_PRESS) scale += 0.01f;
if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_DOWN) == GLFW_PRESS && scale - 0.01f > 0) scale -= 0.01f;

glUseProgram(programID);
draw_Cube(x_Pos, y_Pos, z_Pos, scale, programID);

glfwSwapBuffers(window);
glfwPollEvents();
```

**Vertex Shader:**

```
#version 430 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 vertexColor;

out vec3 fragmentColor;

uniform mat4 MVP;

void main() {
   gl_Position = MVP * vec4(vertexPosition_modelspace,1);

   fragmentColor = vertexColor;
}
```

**Fragment Shader:**

```
#version 430 core

in vec3 fragmentColor;
out vec3 color;

void main(){
  color = fragmentColor;
}
```

**Minimal:**

**Main Loop:**

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
draw_Cube(x_Pos, y_Pos, z_Pos, scale, programID);
glfwSwapBuffers(window);
glfwPollEvents();
```

**Drawing Cube:**

```
GLuint VertexArrayID;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);

static const GLfloat g_vertex_buffer_data[] = {
    -1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f, // triangle 1 : begin
    -1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // triangle 1 : end
};
GLuint vertexbuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_vertex_buffer_data),     g_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 12*3);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

static const GLfloat g_color_buffer_data[] = {
    0.583f,  0.771f,  0.014f,
    0.609f,  0.115f,  0.436f,
    0.327f,  0.483f,  0.844f,
};
GLuint colorbuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &colorbuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorbuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_color_buffer_data), g_color_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);

mat4 Projection = perspective(radians(45.0f), (float)4 / (float)3, 0.1f, 100.0f);
mat4 View = lookAt(
    vec3(4, 3, 3), 
    vec3(0, 0, 0), // looks at the origin
    vec3(0, 1, 0)  // Head is up (set to 0,-1,0 to look upside-down)
);
mat4 Model = mat4(1.0f);
mat4 mvp = Projection * View * Model;
GLuint MatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "MVP");
glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &mvp[0][0]);
```

I can't remove from the shaders, I think.

Comment: Why are you calling `glDrawArrays()` before you've uploaded and bound your vertex color data?  Edit in a [mcve].

Comment: I've tried doing it after but I still got a black cube.

Comment: Ok. Working on it.

Comment: Try to make your color vec4 in fragment shader and type cast fragment color to vec4.Also drawcube gets called every frame and ypu are calling glBufferData every frame? Remove those call and your draw functio  should only have drawarrays call. Move other code to somw init function.

Comment: Using vec4s still doesn't work.